# How to find two records sharing the same Month and Day of birth in SQLITE3

Tags: sqlite

I have a table for PERSON and in this they have a Name and a Birthday.

For example, I have a table called PERSON

```
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES ( 'alice', '1986-10-10');
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES ( 'kate', '1992-10-10');
```

I would like to type in a query that will produce alice and kate ( A query that displays all entries that share month and day, the year doesn't matter). Birthday is used to store this date and I used the Date data type.

I have other values with different birthdates, so I can't seem to figure out the query that will produce alice and kate (because they share the month and day of their birthday)

This is what I have so far, but this is not producing anything:

```
SELECT Name FROM PERSON
WHERE Birthday LIKE '_____XX__XX';
```

Comment: You have the right query, but your pattern has an extra `_` character between the month and day.  `LIKE '____-10-10'` works for me.

Comment: Yes, that works for the values that I have listed here, but I have some values such as 1982-12-12, 1823-12-12, 1992-3-3 and I can't figure out the query to list all names that share birthdates.

I've been trying to figure out the Date() and Time() functions found at: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html and I don't know how to apply them to this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will work as is (with the corrected pattern), but you need to ensure that your dates are all in the correct format.  From the documentation:

```
A time string can be in any of the following formats:

1.  YYYY-MM-DD 
...
```

So you need to use that format for all dates.  "1992-3-3"  will not be recognized as a date; you need to use "1992-03-03".  Or you can use julian dates which makes arithmetic very convenient but reading things a little harder without use of the date/time functions.

If you use the correct ISO date format, then your LIKE clause will work, or you could use the date/time functions to extract a piece of the date., e.g.,

```
SELECT name, strftime('%m-%d',birthday) FROM person;
alice|10-10
kate|10-10
```

so if you wanted you could GROUP BY that term:

```
SELECT strftime('%m-%d',birthday) as mday, count(*) FROM person GROUP BY mday;
```

Or find all distinct values, or whatever you prefer.

For example, you can get a list of all people and all the people sharing birthdays with them by joining Person to itself:

```
SELECT p1.name, p2.name, strftime('%m-%d', p1.birthday) 
FROM person p1 LEFT OUTER JOIN person p2
  ON (strftime('%m-%d',p1.birthday) = strftime('%m-%d',p2.birthday) AND p1.rowid <> p2.rowid) ;
```

That is, join the table to itself using the extracted month-day and exclude joining the row to itself.  Using a left outer join includes people that don't share a birthday with anyone.

Comment: Very, very helpful. I think I understand more.

How would I go about only listing the names that have a match though?

So, alice and kate would be displayed with the other two people who share a birthdate.

Comment: I added an example of getting all matching birthdays.  It might be overkill, but it's easy enough to slim down further.